# Twilio voice calls - error 422

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I am developing an application where I'd like to implement masked numbers between users. The idea is... Assume that you want to call me. Instead of seeing my number via the dashboard and/or order show page, you get a "Call" button. When you click this button it will cause your phone to ring. When you answer your phone, twilio will then attempt to connect you to my number However, the number that you will see will be the twilio number rather than mine.
I am developing in Rails.
I think I am almost there but still I have an error. This is my code:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:collect_call]



def call(gardener_phone,twilio_number)
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["TWILIO_SID"], 
ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])
client.calls.create(
  from: twilio_number,
  to: gardener_phone,
  url: "http://www.****.com/calls.xml"
 )
end

def connect_call
response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
response.dial caller_id: '+4420332*****' do |dial|
  dial.number "+447946*****"
end
render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

I have added this route in routes.rb:

```
post "/calls.xml", to: "users#connect_call"
```

When I click the button, I receive the call from the twilio number however I am not redirected to the other number. I get a voice error. In the twilio dashboard the log says:

```
An attempt to retrieve content from http://www.****.com/calls.xml 
returned the HTTP status code 422

<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8"?>
<hash>
<status type=“integer”>422</status>
<error>Unprocessable Entity</error>
</hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the top of your file you have

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:collect_call]
```

Skipping the verification for `collect_call`. However, your method is called `connect_call`.

Try changing the `skip_before_action` to:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:connect_call]
```

Let me know if that helps at all.